# Self-hosted web app to view raster & vector layers and annotate

Tags: raster, vector, web-mapping, software-recommendations

I'm trying to find a self-hosted web app that allows you to view a number of raster and vector layers on a draggable web map, and then to 'annotate' the map by adding points to the map with associated textual information.

The first part of this is really easy - any sort of web mapping tool will do it. But I can't seem to see any self-hosted tool that will allow that sort of easy annotation?

Part of the issue here is that the users won't be experienced with GIS at all - so going down the path of a full online GIS system isn't really feasible. I'm sure some sort of tool like this must have already been written - does anyone have any suggestions, before I give up and write my own?

Comment: Not sure there's anything off-the-shelf but easy enough to build with leaflet for the map and Django for the web server dealing with new data via POST requests. Do you need logins/security?

Answer (score 1):

I believe My Maps from google will let you share a map so people can add places. Since lots of people know how to use google maps, the interface will be familiar

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, MyMaps seems to struggle with raster layers, and has quite significant limitations on the size of layers. Some sort of self-hosted MyMaps equivalent would be great though.

Comment: Then how about GeoExplorer (http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoexplorer/). It lets you create or edit vector layers on top of a webmap. And for an easier setup, you could use GeoNode, which bundled PostGis, Geoserver and GeoExplorer in one package, letting you upload layers, create maps and edit layers (http://geonode.org/).